# Solidity coverage 0% with hardhat coverage

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I faced a problem: solidity coverage returns that none contract is covered. I have a couple of tests that call these contracts to check specific conditions. As you can see on the images below the functions are exist and tests are passed. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something? Moreover, everything works fine with another project, all versions are the same, all configs +- are the same.
Does somebody know what it can be?
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hey I'm having your same problem. Did you manage to fix that?

Comment: Hey @Allennick. In my case, I changed the hardhat config. Set viaIR: false and optimizer.enabled: false.

Comment: @AGJoYy can you share the hardhat config code if possible?

Answer (score 1):

I had hardhat compilers settings like this before

```
settings: {
    optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 1,
        details: {
            yul: true,
        },
    },
    viaIR: true,
}
```

and I removed viaIR: true, so I receive

```
settings: {
    optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 1,
        details: {
            yul: true,
        },
    },
}
```

And this works for me

Answer (score 1):

For me, adding the below code in solcover.js worked:

```
    ...
    configureYulOptimizer: true,
    solcOptimizerDetails: {
        yul: true,
        yulDetails: {
            optimizerSteps: ""
        },
    },
    ...
```

Solidity: `0.8.19`

Hardhat Compiler Settings: `{"viaIR":true,"optimizer":{"enabled":true, "details": {"yul": true}}}`

However, some tests use higher gas than running tests with the `npx hardhat test`. So, we might need to change some tests accordingly.

Comment: The latest `solidity-coverage` version takes care of this issue natively.